# How to fix this code so that it works correctly

Tags: java, class, processing

How can I fix this code so it works correctly?

It should print `bau bau` and `miao`.

**Code:**

```
class Animal {
   // Nothing to define, this is only an example
}

class Dog extends Animal {  
   void say() {
      print("bau bau");
   }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
   void say() {
      print("miao");
   }
}

void setup() {
   Dog dog = new Dog();
   Cat cat = new Cat();

   ArrayList<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();
   list.add(dog);
   list.add(cat);

   for (Animal obj:list) {
      if (obj.say != null) obj.say(); //error here: say() is undefined
   }
}
```

**Exception:**

`say cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Thank you for the help

Comment: What are you expecting with `obj.say != null`? Do you come from the JavaScript world? ;)

Comment: Because the say() method should be optional, is this not possible in java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `the say() method should be optional` (see the comments of the OP's question), it seems that you need an extra interface, e.g.:

```java
interface Sayable {
    void say();
}
```

Then:

```java
class Dog extends Animal implements Sayable {
    @Override
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("bau bau");
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal implements Sayable {
    @Override
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("miao");
    }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
    // a rabbit unfortunately does not speak,
    // so don't make it implement Sayable
}
```

And:

```java
Dog dog = new Dog();
Cat cat = new Cat();
Rabbit rabbit = new Rabbit();

ArrayList<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();
list.add(dog);
list.add(cat);
list.add(rabbit);

for (Animal obj : list) {
    if (obj instanceof Sayable) {
        Sayable sayable = (Sayable) obj;
        sayable.say();
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
bau bau
miao
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of your `ArrayList` is animal, so there's no guarantee that a `say()` method exists in any subclass of animal.

You can add this guarantee in by making an abstract method as such:

```
abstract class Animal {
   abstract void say();
}
```

This guarantees that all subclasses of `Animal` will have a `say()` method (if they don't, they won't compile.) Note that Animal itself is now abstract, which makes it uninstantiable directly (since any class with abstract methods also has to be abstract.)

If this isn't what you want, an alternative could be to provide a default behaviour in a say method in animal:

```
class Animal {
   @Override
   void say() {
        System.out.println("A bit confused");
   }
}
```

With this behaviour, subclasses aren't forced to implement such a method - if they don't, then they get the default behaviour (as above), if they do then they *override* the default behaviour with their implementation, and that's used instead. Optionally, (but I recommend that you do), then you can use the `@Override` annotation to specify you intended to override a method as above. That way, if you *haven't* overriden it for any reason, it won't compile, allowing you to spot the error early.

Answer (score 3):

For good order, always use `@Override`. This catches typos in method name or parameter types.

```
class Animal {
   //nothing to defines, this is only an example
   void say() {
   }
}

class Dog extends Animal {  
   @Override
   void say() {
      print("bau bau");
   }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
   @Override
   void say() {
      print("miao");
   }
}
```

Now `say()` can be called on any `Animal`, in effect doing nothing (your mention of `say` being optional - a Turtle saying nothing, and hence not having its own overriden `say`).

Comment: +3 and how does it answer op's question

Comment: @JigarJoshi a good remark; added a clarification to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Animal` type doesn't have public (or any other accessible access specified)  field called `say`

```
obj.say
```

Comment: `Animal` doesn't define `say` so when you try to reference an `Animal` object (which might be a `Dog`) it doesn't know `say` exists.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it optional:

```
package com.rei.online;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class Animal {
}

interface Talking {
    void say();
}

class Dog extends Animal implements Talking {
    @Override
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("bau bau");
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal implements Talking {
    @Override
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("miao");
    }
}

class Whatever {
    public static void main(String... args) {
       Dog dog = new Dog();
       Cat cat = new Cat();

       ArrayList<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();
       list.add(dog);
       list.add(cat);

       for (Animal obj:list) {
          if (obj instanceof Talking) {
              Talking talker = (Talking) obj;
              talker.say();
          }
       }
    }
}
```